# Select the first item in a sorted DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with user sortable columns. ItemSorce is bound to a CollectionViewSource that applies a default sort. The CollectionViewSource is in turn bound to an ObservableCollection. I want the first item to be selected when the screen first loads.
setting SelectedIndex doesn't work because I have SelectedItem bound to a property that is initially null, and I need that binding to be two way.

I can't set the property bound to SelectedItem to the first item because the collection is sorted on the view side and I don't know what the first item is.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work for you, but you can try:

1. Give your ViewModel a name (if you have one) so you can access it by its name;
2. Register an event handler to the Loaded event of your DataGrid;
3. In the handler get the first item of the DataGrid through `var firstItem = YourDataGrid.Items.FirstOrDefault() as YourModel;`
4. Set the `SelectedItem` of the ViewModel to the item we've got in point 3. 'YourViewModel.SelectedItem = firstItem;'. If the SelectedItem notify the ui when it changes, aka is observable, your UI should update.